# Apache configuration for serving Django app is not working

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed my **Django** Project on the server, and it is running locally with no problem. I can make migrations and runserver works with no error.

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) in order to use **Apache** to serve the project on **Ubuntu**, but I am having problems. The first one is where you start Django's development server and allow remote connections (`./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`). When I connect from a remote browser, I get this error:

```
Esta página no funciona
189.172.218.174 envió una respuesta no válida.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

I have also made al configurations to serve the app with Apache, but when a try to connect to the server from a browser, I just get a blank page. No error or anything.

This is my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCDigitalProject/tcdigital/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/static
        <Directory /home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCDigitalProject/tcdigital/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCdigitalProject/tcdigital/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/TCDigital>
            <Files wsgi.py>
               Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess TCDigital python-home=/home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCDigitalProject/tcdigital/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigitalVenv python-path=/home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCDigitalProjec/tcdigital/TCdigitalBackend/TCDigital
        WSGIProcessGroup TCDigital
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/linuxmidtc/Code/TCDigitalProject/tcdigital/TCDigitalBackend/TCDigital/TCDigital/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**
I have tried @mohammedabdelawel answer, but whit the same result. This is my current ufw status:

```
linuxmidtc@servermidtc:~$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 6] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in ufw that don't allow http, try follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04)
this will help you config ufw on ubuntu

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work. You can see the ufw current status in the body of the question